# compare ordinal type in data mining

Tags: data-mining, ordinals

I have several variables
That type of them is ordinal type .

never < rarely < occasionally < often

I would calculate the amount of nearly two variables. 
Is it possible ؟

For Example 1 : v1 = often v2= often 
so v1 is completely near v2

For Example 2 :
v1 = occasionally & v2 = often

For Example 3 :
v1 = rarely & v2 = often

so  V1 and v2 values in example 2 ​​are closer together than values in Example 3 .

How can I show degree close of them with a number?

Comment: What programming language do you want this in?

Comment: Check out http://stats.stackexchange.com they might be able to help you there. Your question, so far, is not about programming.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]. You need to specify your own personal effort in solving this problem in order to get the community out here to help you. Please also go through [ask] and the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
let never = 0, rarely = 1, occasionally = 2, often = 3
result = absolute_value(v1 - v2)   //where result=0 is the closest and result=3 is the farthest
```